# CSS How to properly replace links by button background

Tags: css, positioning, styling

I'm trying to replace the links on my app with a button background. However the link text won't center horizontally neither vertically. I'm using the property "background-position: center center;" which I assume would solve my problem.

My HTML:

```
<a class="violetButtonLarge" href="#">My Link</a>
```

CSS:

```
.violetButtonLarge {
    display: block; 
    width: 304px; 
    height: 41px;
    background: url(../images/violetButton_large.png) no-repeat center center;
    border:none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

My image:

[image]

What I'm I doing wrong here? This is what I get:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should throw it on JSfiddle, that way we can play with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text-align:center` and `line-height:41px` to align the text in the vertical and horizontal center.

```
.violetButtonLarge {
    display: block; 
    width: 304px; 
    height: 41px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8zvb.png) no-repeat center center;
    border:none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:41px;
}
```

**Example: http://tinkerbin.com/q5VZR1At**

Answer (score 0):

```
a.button {
    background: transparent url('violetButton_large.png') no-repeat scroll top right;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font: normal 12px arial, sans-serif;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding-right: 18px; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
<a class="button" href="#" onclick="this.blur();"> … </a>
```

Comment: there is no need to place `display:block;` on an element that has `float` – inline element will become blocky when floated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should set the padding, then you don't need to set the width and height. The `vertical-align: baseline` helps to set them on the same line with "real" input buttons.

```
.button {
  padding: .4em 1.6em .44em 1.6em;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Edit: Sorry i didn't saw the image in your code, maybe you should get a glimpse at this great example: [CSS Gradient Buttons](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-gradient-buttons).

Comment: line-height with the height of the image is better and more generic, it will center text not depending on the font-size

Comment: @gryzzly - Yes you are right, i already edited the text, i didn't see the image and thought it was made with pure CSS.